Easyadmin 4 : link between entity without relation in page index
I'm working on a project with symfony 6 and easyadmin 4 to create an administration service for a site.
I have dozens of entities and especially one entity (Entity_History) that is used to record actions performed on other entities by a service. Given the number of entities, there is no relationship between these entities and the Entity_History entity.
But in the index page of each entity, I'd like to retrieve the last modification date of each record.
I've made a HistoryTrait to do this and it's currently blocking. In fac, the query executes, but when I have a value, I get the “unreachable” result on the record's line, and "none" when there's no value to retrieve. (I'm not an English speaker, so I don't know the exact English terms.)
I don't know what could be blocking the rendering of the transaction
I try to make A trait (and a service before) to retrieve data.
My CRUDController (one of the ten entities that must retrieve the date from Entity_History)
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\LocationType;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Action;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Actions;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateTimeField;



class LocationTypeCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return LocationType::class;
    }

    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
    return $actions
        ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::NEW, function (Action $action) {
            return $action->setLabel('Ajouter un typer de lieu');
        })
        ->update(Crud::PAGE_NEW, Action::SAVE_AND_RETURN, function (Action $action) {
            return $action->setLabel('Créer le type de lieu');
        })
        ->update(Crud::PAGE_NEW, Action::SAVE_AND_ADD_ANOTHER, function (Action $action) {
            return $action->setLabel('Créer et ajouter un autre type de lieu');
        })
        ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::EDIT, function (Action $action) {
            return $action
                ->setIcon('fa fa-edit')
                ->setLabel(false)
                ->setHtmlAttributes([
                    'title' => 'Modifier cet élément',
                ])
                ->displayAsLink()
                ->addCssClass('btn btn-sm btn-light');
        })
        ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DELETE, function (Action $action) {
            return $action
                ->setIcon('fa fa-trash')
                ->setLabel(false)
                ->setHtmlAttributes([
                    'title' => 'Supprimer cet élément',
                ])
                ->displayAsLink()
                ->addCssClass('btn btn-sm btn-light');
        });    
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
        ->addFormTheme('admin/form.html.twig')
        ->setEntityLabelInSingular('Type de lieu')
        ->setEntityLabelInPlural('Type de lieux')
        ->setPageTitle('new', 'Ajouter un nouveau type de lieu')
        ->showEntityActionsInlined();
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
        TextField::new('type'),
        DateTimeField::new('lastModificationDate')
            ->setLabel('Dernière modification')
            ->setVirtual(true)
            ->formatValue(function ($value, $entity) {
                return $entity->getLastModificationDate($this->entityManager);
                
            })
            ->onlyOnIndex(),
        ];
    }
}

HistoryTrait to make relation beetween one fo entity and Entity_History
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin\Trait;

use App\Entity\EntityHistory;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

trait HistoryTrait

{
    public function getLastModification(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): ?EntityHistory
    {
        return $entityManager->getRepository(EntityHistory::class)
            ->findOneBy(
                ['entityName' => get_class($this), 'entityId' => $this->getId()],
                ['dateAction' => 'DESC']
            );
    }

    public function getLastModificationDate(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        $lastModification = $this->getLastModification($entityManager);
        return $lastModification ? $lastModification->getDateAction() : null;
    }

    public function getLastModificationUser(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): ?string
    {
        $lastModification = $this->getLastModification($entityManager);
        return $lastModification ? $lastModification->getUser() : null;
    }

    public function getLastModificationAction(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): ?string
    {
        $lastModification = $this->getLastModification($entityManager);
        return $lastModification ? $lastModification->getAction() : null;
    }
}

    

Entity_History
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\EntityHistoryRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EntityHistoryRepository::class)]
class EntityHistory
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $entityName = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $entityId = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $action = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
    private array $oldValues = [];

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'json')]
    private $newValues = [];

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $dateAction = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'entityHistories')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $user = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): static
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEntityName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->entityName;
    }

    public function setEntityName(string $entityName): static
    {
        $this->entityName = $entityName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEntityId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->entityId;
    }

    public function setEntityId(int $entityId): static
    {
        $this->entityId = $entityId;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAction(): ?string
    {
        return $this->action;
    }

    public function setAction(string $action): static
    {
        $this->action = $action;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOldValues(): array
    {
        return $this->oldValues;
    }

    public function setOldValues(array $oldValues): static
    {
        $this->oldValues = $oldValues;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOldValuesJson(): string
    {
        $json = json_encode($this->oldValues);
        return $json;
    }

    public function getNewValuesJson(): string
    {
        $json = json_encode($this->newValues);
        return $json;
    }

    public function getNewValues(): array
    {
        return $this->newValues;
    }

    public function setNewValues(array $newValues): static
    {
        $this->newValues = $newValues;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getDateAction(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateAction;
    }

    public function setDateAction(\DateTimeInterface $dateAction): static
    {
        $this->dateAction = $dateAction;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): static
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
}

